# Convert pdf to word document using php

Tags: php, pdf, ms-word, libreoffice, doc

I am trying to convert pdf to doc using Libreoffice in php which isn't working.

```
path/to/soffice --infilter="writer_pdf_import" --convert-to doc file.pdf /path/to/test.docx
```

PS: Is there any other better solutions to parse pdf and extract images not just text and then covert it to doc representations.

Comment: that command line is not php can you show me your PHP code?

Comment: shell_exec("path/to/soffice --infilter="writer_pdf_import" --convert-to doc file.pdf /path/to/test.docx");

Comment: I added my answer.  Good luck

Comment: did you get the solution? Please share if you got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you didn't show us the error, so I don't know why your command isn't working. But, that command is not a [Libreoffice](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Starting_the_Software_With_Parameters)'s command. You are using a [soffice](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-soffice/)'s command:

This an example using [libreoffice](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Starting_the_Software_With_Parameters) Software:

```sh
path/to/libreoffice --headless --invisible --convert-to doc your_source_file.pdf
```

### Note:

This solution only converts the text without the images.

### Alternative 01:

If [LibreOffice](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Starting_the_Software_With_Parameters) doesn't work on your system, [Abiword](https://www.abisource.com/) also works in a similar way.

1. Install **Abiword** by typing following command in terminal:

```sh
sudo apt-get install abiword
```

Then perform the conversion:

```sh
abiword --to=doc your_source_file.pdf
```

### Alternative 02:

If you want to keep using the **soffice**'s command, probably you can use this syntax:

```sh
path/to/soffice --headless --convert-to <TargetFileExtension>:<NameOfFilter> your_source_file.pdf
```

In your example use "MS Word 2007 XML" for `doc` files or "Microsoft Word 2007/2010/2013 XML" and "Microsoft Word 2007-2013 XML" for `docx` as the filter:

```sh
path/to/soffice --headless --convert-to docx:"Microsoft Word 2007/2010/2013 XML" your_source_file.pdf
```

[Here](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Framework/Article/Filter/FilterList_OOo_3_0) you can find more filters.